# how to tag friends in video using share dialog method

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a feature in my website that I need to get all user's facebook friends name and photos, and create a video with those photos.User can share created videos using facebook. 
 As of now I am retrieving friends using taggable_friends method which needs to be submitted for Facebook review.
 I have red that taggable_friends can only be used  in order to tag friend.
 I am sharing video using share dialog . Anybody please guide me how to tag friends using share dialog. 
 I can share video with out tagging my friends but I am afraid if facebook rejects my app.

Comment: You are not allowed to use `taggable_friends` for anything else but tagging. With API v2, your app will not be able to get all friends of a user any more, only those that are users of the app as well – and you are not allowed to use `taggable_friends` to try and circumvent that limitation, it will not get approved.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need any approval for using the share dialog, and you don´t even need to authorize the user for that. The user can tag his friends on his own in the dialog and you are not allowed to prefill the message dialog anyway according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

That being said, you can send your App to review without a problem, nothing happens to you if it gets rejected, you can just change your App and send it in for review again. But you are not allowed to use `taggable_friends` for anything else but tagging.

Comment: My doubt is Can I use taggable_friends method for fetching friend's details?

Comment: you can only use taggable_friends for tagging. you should not store the details, you don´t get the user id anyway, only a tagging token that is not valid forever.

Comment: thanks lushn.. I will retrieve friends  details using taggable_friends ,create video with the friends photos and share it on facebook using share dialog where I can tag friends. Is this possible?

Comment: as i said, just forget about taggable_friends, the share dialog does not need authorization and the user can just tag friends on his own.